# Error SSL in Apache with Existing Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

Today I had space issues on my server due to backups taking too much space. That problem was solved, but since then the ssl isn't working anymore for the SSL certificate I bought.

I mean, it was working fine before, after the space issue it stopped working. I trying to re-upload the files and that didn't help.

Should I re-issue the certificate?

The error I get is:
[Sun Mar 23 12:22:59 2014] [error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /home/**/forumantinom.csr
[Sun Mar 23 12:22:59 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Sun Mar 23 12:22:59 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error

I read another thread here, which happened  after configuration, and the problem was solved by re-copying the content of the file.

I ftp'ed the files, and they were exatly the same size as the existing ones.

Comment: One last detail is that the default ssl certificate that came with kloxo works fine :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have configured wrong certificate to use. In my opinion /home/**/forumantinom.csr contains a certificate request not certificate or private key coresponding to the certificate. Try and open it in an editor if it's true.

What you have to do is configure right certificate and private key. Please look at the following [guide](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm).

Comment: That's embarassing, you were right, somehow I used the wrong file, I must have mistaken the file name when I was recovering the configuration.